# Firebase CocoaPods not found Firebase Property

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

I am new to firebase, but many other cocoapods succefully i setup and used. Right now i am facing problem on fairebase Cocoapods after complete setup.
I cant acess firebase property after adding header file.

```
  #import <Firebase/Firebase.h>


    Firebase *myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"my firebase url"]];
```

[image]
here shows undeclared identifier Firebase error. 
I start explore pods file in the project then i come to know it doesn't contain Firebase class files and related class. 
I did steps as per Quick start guide line in firebase website. But I don't know why file not exist. Please help what i did wrong.

pod version Firebase (3.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Firebase SDK 3.2.0 has several breaking changes compared to the old version 2.x, therefore the old Quick Start guide is completely obsolete. All classes have been renamed, and the integration process is different.

You must follow the new guide [on firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) instead.

Comment: Or, if for some reason you want to force version 2.5.x, you must use a different operator in the Podfile. `~> 2.5.1` would not allow a major version upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2.5.0. If you use 2.5.1, you have to use Google Service plist for your Firebase Reference

```
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
```